# Pandas (pd.concat) puts each dataframe into a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting the following workflow:

1. Import large .csv file and isolate by column.
2. Remove duplicates
3. Import Second, smaller .csv file and isolate by column.
4. Concatenate the two into a single column in a dataframe and remove the duplicates so I can check the diff.

Here's the code I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=0, usecols=[4]).drop_duplicates()

# Place a checkpoint here to verify the file wrote correctly.

df1.to_csv('orders_new.csv', index=False, header=None, encoding='utf-8')


df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', header=0, usecols=[0])

# Place a checkpoint here to verify the file wrote correctly.

df2.to_csv('tables_new.csv', index=False, header=None, encoding='utf-8')


new_dataframe = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

new_dataframe.to_csv('output.csv')
```

When I look in the output.csv file, file1 has been properly imported and dupes removed and dropped into the new file, but when I get to the point where that file ends and the next begins, the file 2 data ends up in the row to the right of it.

Looking for some guidance here.

Thanks!

I tried doing a simple concat within pandas, and it worked but the output was in two columns, and not one.